# Turn set of urls in to a regex pattern (optional patterns)

Tags: regex

Using an arbitrary set of urls (eg: http://api.longurl.org/v2/services) what is the best way to turn this list into a regex?

Is this appropriate regex?

```
(((easyuri|eepurl|eweri)\.com)|((migre|mke|myloc)\.me)|etc...)'
```

Can you do multiple levels of optional patterns like that?

Comment: The question is not how the regex looks like but what a good solution is for your purpose. What are you planning to do?

Comment: I guess that could be the case... I just want to slurp the xml (longurl api), grok it into a regex, and match urls against that regex. I just need to see if a given url matches a domain/(/sld)/tld entity in that set.

Answer (score 0):

I see different ways to accomplish this.

1. Use XPath and try to select a node given the current URL.
2. Parse the xml into a dictionary and test your current URL if it exists as a key.
3. Store the domains of the XML in a database, index the url field and query your current URL.
4. If performance is not an issue: Match the current URL against the entire XML file as text.
5. Perhaps there are more ideas.

Building a regex from the XML does not seem to me a good idea since all the other solutions appear to me far more easy to develop.

Comment: The problem with all these options is that they all require an initial regex on the user input url. I have to hope that I get the correct portion of the input url and match against the given set (either via xpath, a dictionary loolup a sql like select, etc). I think it much more direct to create a regex out of the known set and match unknowns against it. This regex will be cached and periodically recreated.

Answer (score 0):

**OP'S ANSWER:**

Well it turns out that this does work:

```
/((?:easyuri|eepurl|eweri)\.com)|((?:migre|mke|myloc)\.me)/
```

Run against this:

```
easyuri.com eepurl.comer eweri.us migre.me mke.memo myloc.em
```

You get this:

```
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => easyuri.com
        [1] => eepurl.com
        [2] => migre.me
        [3] => mke.me
    )
```

But the easiest way would just be something like this:

```
/0rz\.tw|1link\.in|1url\.com|2\.gp|2big\.at|etc\.\.\./
```

Regex helps you complicate things more than is possible with other methods. ;P

**Here's the PHP I eventually used to create the regex:**

Assumes that you have cURL'd http://api.longurl.org/v2/services and converted the xml to an array called `$urlShorteners` like: `$urlShorteners = array('0rz.tw', '1link.in', 'etc...');`

```
foreach($urlShorteners as $url) {
    $urls[] = array_reverse(explode('.', $url));
}

foreach($urls as $url) {
    $tldKeys[array_shift($url)][] = $url;
}

foreach($tldKeys as $tld => $doms) {
    if($tld != '') {
         $subPattern = array();
         foreach($doms as $subDomain) {
             $subPattern[] = implode("\.", array_reverse($subDomain));
         }
         if (count($subPattern) > 1) $optionPattern[] = "((?:" . implode("|", $subPattern) . ")\." . $tld . ")";
         else $optionPattern[] = "(" . $subPattern[0] . "\." . $tld . ")";
    }
}
$regex = '/' . implode('|', $optionPattern) . '/';
echo $regex . "\n";
```